# Submit a form without changing the url in rails with turbo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails

I have a rails form that I successfully submit with turbo

```
= form_with url: submit_path, multipart: true, data: { turbo_frame: 'document_table_content' } do |f|
Form-row
  = f.submit t('.submit'), class: 'Button'
```

When I submit the form the url changes to `submit_path`, I want to keep the url the same, is that possible?

Comment: I think you should be able to do it by setting `data-turbo-action="replace"` (the default is advance).

Comment: Tried that it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Turbo form submission only accepts `redirect` or `turbo_stream` in response. If you want to stay on current page and you really don't want to perform any changes in it after submission, in your controller render a turbo_stream like this:

```
def save_object
  object.update! params
  render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.remove('dummy-uniq-dom-id')
end
```

However, you may want to update portion of the same page using following code:

```
render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.replace('id-of-dom-element',
  partial: "path/to/render", locals: {if: 'any'}
)
```

Note that `turbo_stream` has currently 7 actions: [Read here](https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/streams#the-seven-actions)